# 301 Every request to root (including all subdomains)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Ok here is the question

I would like to 301 redirect all request to www.domain.com, this should include all subdomains except www. off course.

Example

```
info.domain.com/example > 301 redirect > www.domain.com
www.domain.com/examples > 301 redirect > www.domain.com
domain.com              > 301 redirect > www.domain.com
domain.com/example      > 301 redirect > www.domain.com
```

The code I have so far is:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
    RewriteRule ^.+$ / [R=301,NC,L]
```

But this does not take care of the wildcard subdomain redirection...

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$    [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^.+$   http://www.domain.com/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be ``HTTP_HOST``?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The only thing now is that it does not do a wildcard redirect for subdomains to www.domain.com Is there any way to incorporate that? Thanks

Comment: Yes I do you CPanel direcAdmin

Comment: Which one? CPanel? or directAdmin?

Comment: I am sorry I use CPanel

Comment: Login to your CPanel, go to **Sub-domains** and create a sub-domain named `*.domain.com`. Set its document root the same as your `www.domain.com`.